# LinkedIn V2 version API "Not enough permissions to access /me GET"

Tags: linkedin-api

**Need Help Folks,**

Does anyone able make call to LinkedIn **V2/me** version.
I'm able to make successful API call to V1 version got response as member required information.

**https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,headline,location,industry,picture-url,summary,positions,public-profile-url,site-standard-profile-request,last-modified-timestamp)?format=json**

When calling **https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me**?format=json ,method :GET in postman by access token in header as part of Authorization.It is throwing below error

Response :

```
{

    "serviceErrorCode": 100,

    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me",

    "status": 403

}
```

I used the same **OAuth2.0** access token for both V1 & V2 version. Since August 10 2015 have `r_basicprofile` permission for V1 version in LinkedIn consumer application platform.

There is no issue with V1 API calls from our application. Linkedin will be sunset V1 version so need to use public API's only as per restriction from LinkedIn side for X application DLP.

What are the **LinkedIn public API** endpoints & required API access permission ?

How to get  `r_liteprofile` permission ?

I want basic member profile information like first-name, last-name, email-address, headline, location, industry, picture-url, summary, positions.

Which API have to call to get the above data ?

Thanks you in advance ):-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using V2 and you did not taken permission to use r_basicprofile 
then either apply for permission  to use r_basicprofile  to linkedin 
or use r_liteprofile + r_emailaddress

r_liteprofile for firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id
r_emailaddress  for getting  emailAddress

Check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: Now we are using V1 version and r_basicprofile access is enable for application but LinkedIn not ready to continue the agreement with us they decided to stop using of V1 and they suggested to use only V2 version public LinkedIn API's what are those ? . 
Could you please tell me How to call r_liteprofile & r_emailaddress Endpoint URL ?

Comment: Now r_basicprofile will work with V1 only ( till 1st match). 
For :  r_liteprofile 
 https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me OR  https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams)) For : r_emailaddress  : https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))

Comment: Thanks KPSingh !! Could you please help me out from above permission 403-error code  V2 version of LInkedIn?

Comment: Yes sure : First check at Linkedin - My App- Default permission or Added products and permissions. I think r_liteprofile  permission is not there with your app , Check then let me know please

Comment: Yes. you are right ! App doesn't r_liteprofile permission. As per LinkedIn doc If application has made a successful LinkedIn v1 API request from September 1, 2018 to December 17, 2018, It has immediate access to the v2 API but don't have. I'll  try call to V2 API  by creating new app Just I wanted to know      
 ,How to request r_liteprofile permission for newly  created application from LinkedIn developer platform.

Comment: Check i have posted one link : according to that document ( All developer applications created on the LinkedIn Developer Portal after January 14, 2019 have access to the LinkedIn v2 API by default.) : So created after 14th that will come by default

Comment: I shall create new Application after Jan 14, .Thank you so much      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: hi, so for old application which is the correct way to implement API calls? I am getting only the `r_liteprofile` response for `api.linkedin.com/v2/me` , but I have the full_profile permission for my app. OAuth seems to be fine,because I am getting the access_token, and I have added the `r_fullprofile` scope in the authentication parameters. Anyone please help!